# Method to calculate solution of a linear equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, nullspace

I am searching a solution method for the following equation system of equation systems:

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be s.p.d. Matrices and $O$ be the zero matrix of the same size. Further let $f\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be given vector and $0$ the zero vector. I am searching for a numerical method to find the solution vectors $x_1, x_2  \in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
O &  A 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x_1  \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
f \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I tried to solve this in Python with (`scipy.linalgscipy.linalg: lu_factor, lu_solve`). The problem, I only get the trivial solution $x_2 = 0$. Is there a way to solve the equation system of equation systems for non-trivial solutions?

Comment: That looks like a saddle point system / Lagrange multiplier system gone awry $[\mathbf A \mathbf B; \mathbf B^T \mathbf 0]$. I'd double check your reference material / formulation, then ask a followup. There are special methods (both iterative and direct) for those kinds of systems.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way because there is no solution to the given system with  $x_2 \neq 0$. This is because the second block of the equation system reads $Ax_2 = 0$, which has no non-trivial solutions because $A$ is SPD (Otherwise $x_2$ would be an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to a zero eigenvalue).

Comment: Oh you are totally correct. I overlooked the fact of spd. Maybe something in my calculation is not correct. I will write again!